# how can I pass value from django forms to Excel?

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I have a model with static values that I want to use in my model methods and 1 column with values that the user needs to insert called `number_of_units`.

What I want to do is export the `CostCalculator` but the value in the `number_of_units` column should be taken from Django form, not from the model.

How can export the value from `number_of_units` to the excel column?
The form is saved successfully and I can see value from the form in the admin panel but in Excel, I see the value 0 in all rows. It seems that it takes only fixed values that are in the model but doesn't the value from the form. How can I fix that and pass the value from the form to Excel?

forms.py

```
class CalculatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    number_of_units = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)

    class Meta: 
        model = CostCalculator
        fields = ('number_of_units',)
```

resources.py

```
class CostCalculatorResource(resources.ModelResource):
    related_product__title = Field(attribute='related_product__title', column_name='Product')
    number_of_units = Field(attribute='number_of_units')

    class Meta:
        model = CostCalculator
```

models.py

```
class CostCalculator(models.Model):
    related_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='related_product')
    title_component = models.ForeignKey(CalculatorServiceComponent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    number_of_units = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
class ModelDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Product
    form_class = CalculatorForm
    template_name = 'ModelDetailView.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        number_of_units = form.cleaned_data['number_of_units']
        filter_qs = CostCalculator.objects.filter(related_product__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        dataset = CostCalculatorResource().export(filter_qs, number_of_units)
        form.save()
        response = HttpResponse(dataset.xlsx, content_type="xlsx")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=cost_calculator.xlsx'
        return response
```

Comment: `the value in the number_of_units column should be taken from Django form, not from the model` . What do you mean by this? The data of the form is saved in the database through the model. The data which you see on the admin panel comes from the database through the models themselves.

Comment: My problem is that when I click submit it exports data correctly to Excel except column number_of_units because it shows 0 in all rows and I don't know why is that. However when I go to admin panel I see that new item with the correct number_of_units that was inserted by user in form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the lines below:

```
dataset = CostCalculatorResource().export(filter_qs, number_of_units)
form.save()
```

You are first trying to read the database and then save the model. Since the default value of number_of_units is zero you are getting all zeros. Try saving the form first and then accessing that database.

```
form.save()      
dataset = CostCalculatorResource().export(filter_qs, number_of_units)
```